# How to optimize date transformation in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date column `CUR_DATE` in NUMBER(10) (20210821) data type in DB and when I starting some executions with transforming I have a very tough issues with operation time.

for ex. I need to get data for the last 2 months from the current day, so I use transformation like this in my WHERE clause:

```
and trunc(to_date(CUR_DATE,'yyyymmdd'),'mm') >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)
```

and if I don't change date type of course it runs faster

```
and CUR_DATE >= 20220201
```

So maybe there will be solution which allows me execute data for last two months?

Comment: Storing a date value in a number (or even worse, varchar) column is a bad idea. The performance problem you have is a direct result of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the opposite:

```
and cur_date >= to_number(to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1), 'yyyymmdd'))
```

if you must. Why? Because - I presume - there's an index on `cur_date` column. When you *mess with it* (apply various functions), index is no longer used. You *could* create a function-based index, though.

```
SQL> select to_number(to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1), 'yyyymmdd')) val from dual;

       VAL
----------
  20220201

SQL>
```

---

What you really should do is to store dates into `DATE`, not `NUMBER` datatype columns.

Comment: looks like it could be my solution and yes, the way of DB storage are in mess. anyway thanks a lot for your suggestion - didn't think about this way